# How to create image in python and save it

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I want to create an image and store it as a file using python.

I expect the output to be an image with color blocks of black or white, and the image must have 6x6 blocks of random of white or black color blocks.

Comment: Images in OpenCV are represented as 2D or 3D arrays. 2D arrays are grayscale, and generally have values between 0 and 255 with a `dtype` of `np.uint8`, where 0 is black and 255 is white. Try creating a matrix of 0s and 255s and see where you get stuck. Hint: you can use `np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8)` to generate a matrix of zeros (a black image) with a specified height and width, and then you can just set some subset of those elements to white (that is, 255).

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411453/2836621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can use this code to solve that problem:

```
#Import all libraries we will use
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2

#let's create a 6 x 6 matrix with all pixels in black color
img = np.zeros((6,6,3),np.uint8)

#let's use "for" cycle to change colorspace of pixel in a random way
for x in range(6):
    for y in range(6):
        #We use "0" for black color (do nothing) and "1" for white color (change pixel value to [255,255,255])
        value = random.randint(0,1)
        if value == 1:
            img[x,y] = [255,255,255]

#save our image as a "png" image
cv2.imwrite("6_x_6.png",img)
```

---