# How do I create a checkerboard of two specific colors with python

Tags: python, numpy

I have managed to create a black and white checkerboard like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

checkers = np.tile( np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]]), (16 // 2, 16 // 2))
```

but now I am struggling to transform that into - sa - a blue and yellow checkerboard.

I tried a lambda transform like this:

```
f = lambda x: [0, 255, 0] if x else [255, 255, 255]

checkers = checkers.reshape((256))
checkers = f(checkers)
```

but I get an error that says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

which makes me think that I haven't fully understood how lambdas apply to numpy arrays.

I also tried

```
np.where(checkers == 0, [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255])
```

but I get

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,16) (3,) (3,)
```

So, how do I get a two-color checkerboard instead of a black and white one?

Comment: Minor detail regarding how you create your checkerboard: you could use `np.eye(2)` to create your 2x2 cell.

Comment: One example here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411453/2836621

Comment: While the linked answer does show a working method for applying a function to each value in the array, it really shouldn't be used. I realise that this is a simple toy problem and performance isn't important, but working with numpy arrays using Python for loops is REALLY bad practice. It leads to TERRIBLE performance since the iteration is happening in Python instead of being compiled to machine code, as it is if you use Numpy functions/operators. Still, worth mentioning that it is possible to manually index arrays and this sometimes helps with debugging etc.

Comment: Actually, checking the linked answer again I see that most answers are using pure PIL, which doesn't have many of the capabilities Numpy has and therefore requires the use of slow Python looping. Just do that in Numpy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of your answer is very close to being correct, however it's giving you an error: the operands could not be broadcast together. Operands is just referring to the function arguments, `checkers == 0`, green and blue. So it's a broadcasting problem. You should read through the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), they'll really change your understanding of Numpy and make it way more useful.

Your problem is that you have a `checkers` array, which is 2D, 16x16, and you want it to "magically" get converted to a 3D array, which is 16x16x3. Numpy doesn't do this sort of magic conversion. If the last dimension of your array is 1, Numpy will helpfully repeat (broadcast) the array for you to allow you to multiply it with the other arrays (or whatever you want to do), so you don't have to manually tile it across all three colour channels. Otherwise it will just throw an error.

The solution is to add a 1 dimension to your `checkers` array. The simplest way of doing this is

```py
np.where(checkers[..., np.newaxis] == 0, [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255])
```

which adds another dimension to the end of your array, and therefore can be broadcast with your colour.

Edit: Regarding why your `lambda` approach didn't work, I'm not sure if you expected `lambda` to be something special, but it's really very little different from a regular function. So what you're essentially doing is

```
checkers = [0, 255, 0] if checkers else [255, 255, 255]
```

i.e. passing the entire `checkers` array to the function in one go. Python then tries to check if `checkers` is true with `bool(checkers)` which is ambiguous, and it therefore tells you to use `np.all` or `np.any` to reduce the entire array to a single value. But that's not what you want to do anyway.

There are functions such as [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) and [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) which allow you to apply a function to all values, but you very rarely need to do this. Your second approach is much better, you just need to understand broadcasting better.